# normality of moduli of prym curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Is the moduli space of Prym curves (curves $C$ with square root of $\mathcal{O}_C$, compactified via admissible covers - by Beauville) of a given genus $g$ normal? Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various references.  The one I like is the following, particularly Remark 1.3.3.

MR2007376 (2005b:14049) Reviewed
Abramovich, Dan(1-BOST); Corti, Alessio(4-CAMB); Vistoli, Angelo(I-BOLO)
Twisted bundles and admissible covers. (English summary)
Special issue in honor of Steven L. Kleiman.
Comm. Algebra 31 (2003), no. 8, 3547–3618.
14H10 (14A20 14H30)
http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0106211.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The stack $\overline{\mathcal{P}}_{g}$ of Prym curves is a smooth Deligne-Mumford stack. This implies that its coarse moduli space $\overline{P}_{g}$ is normal with at most fine quotient singularities.